# Program type already present: com.google.zxing.ChecksumException

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I try using zxing library to scan a qrcode, there's no error until I run the app like this:

```
Program type already present: com.google.zxing.ChecksumException

Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: com.google.zxing.ChecksumException, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

[image]

here's my gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.std.scanner"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0'
}
```

i think i should using "exclude" in my gradle dependecies, but I don't know how to write the code. please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: [ZXing Readme](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/README.md) says only SDK 19+ is supported. You have set it to 18.

Comment: @SaurabhThorat I have tried change to minSdkVersion 19 but it doesn't work..

Comment: Try changing support library version to 27.1.1

Comment: @SaurabhThorat doesn't work, still error :(

Comment: Try setting it to 25.3.1. ZXing have done that in their [sample](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/sample/build.gradle#L64)

Comment: do you have any jar file in libs folder corresponding to zxing? coz your dependency graph does not show any duplicate.

Comment: It works but then I get Duplicate Class com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat found in modules and the solution for that is to add this exclude. So I am stuck in a loop.

Answer (score 8):

solve by  add in build.gradle (app)

```
configurations {
    implementation.exclude group: 'com.google.zxing'
}
```

Comment: It works but now just change it to-                                                                        
configurations                                                                                                                            {
implementation.exclude group: 'com.google.zxing'                                                                               }

Comment: This can be added anywhere in the build.gradle file for the application, correct?

Comment: Add it inside the dependencies{} block where all other packages are declared.

dependencies{
configurations {
    implementation.exclude group: 'com.google.zxing'
}
}

Answer (score 7):

I was getting the same error except it was the com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat.
Turned out i had the BarcodeFormat in the app from a .jar library i had in /libs.

Have you tried searching for ChecksumException class in you app by pressing 
Ctrl + N and typing "ChecksumException" ?

Comment: You saved my lunch.

Comment: In short: implement library in gradle rather than using JAR file.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was i added a plugin (qrcode) in pubspec.yml which overwrite another class defined from another plugin (animated_qr_code_scanner), and then exist a conflict between plugins (and classes). 
You can try comenting the last added plugin to locate the used classes.